# Use the same value in the test and in the method to be tested

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, mockito

**Method to be tested:**

```
public boolean isValidStudent(String fName, String lName){
    Student student = new Student(fName, lName);//-----------this creates problem
    return (studentDao.get(student).isEmpty())?false : true;        
}
```

The below test fails because the method stub always returns an empty list, when I have specifically specified it to return the list I have created.
It seems that the student object in the test and the method are different. What can I do to make it work? I fixed this by changing the method signature in my second approach below. But I want to do it without changing my method.

```
@Mock
Service service;

@Test
public void isValidStudent(){
    studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    studentList.add(new Student());
    studentList.add(new Student());

    Student student = new Student("Tom", "Clancy");//---this creates problem. 

    when(studentDao.get(student)).thenReturn(studentList);
    assertTrue(service.isValidStudent("Tom", "Clancy"));
}
```

**Second approach that works:**

In this approach, I changed the method signature to accept student object instead and it worked fine. I instantiate the student object only once in my test and use it for method stubbing as well as pass it to the method under test.

```
public boolean isValidStudent(Student student){
    return (studentDao.get(student).isEmpty())?false : true;        
}

@Mock
Service service;

@Test
public void isValidStudent(){
    studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    studentList.add(new Student());
    studentList.add(new Student());

    Student student = new Student("Tom", "Clancy");

    when(studentDao.get(student)).thenReturn(studentList);
    assertTrue(service.isValidStudent(student));
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `return (studentDao.get(student).isEmpty())?false : true;` <-- can be replaced with `return !studentDao.get(student).isEmpty();`

Comment: Also, is your `service` a `mock()` or a `spy()`?

Comment: So how does your second approach work since in your code you don't mock calls to `.isValidStudent()`?

Comment: It returns the studentList I have defined in the test method and the test passes.

Comment: Oh, sorry, those are two distinct classes; OK, then, can you show what `service` is?

Comment: .isValidStudent() calls method studentDao.get(student) which I have mocked in my test and this call returns "studentList" which has 2 objects in it.

Comment: Hmm, does your `Student` class implement `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`?

Comment: No it doesn't implement equals() or hashCode(). I could add that if that may help.

Comment: It probably will, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypothesis: your `Student` class does not implement `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`.

By default, `when()` you mock a method call, mockito will check whether its argument(s) `.equals()` the one(s) you have passed it as (an) argument(s) to the mocked method.

However, if you don't implement `.equals()`, then you will have the case that:

```
final Student s1 = new Student("foo", "bar");
final Student s2 = new Student("foo", "bar");
s1.equals(s2); // <--- FALSE!
```

And this is what happens here. In your first scenario, you create a `Student` which appears, to you, *logically* equal but that is not what Mockito wants. Therefore, in your first scenario, `.get()` will return `null`.

In your second however, you pass the *same reference*; since you don't implement `.equals()`, `Object`'s `.equals()` takes place, and for this `.equals()` implementation, `obj1.equals(obj2)` if and only if `obj1 == obj2` -- which is the case. Continuing the code above, in your case:

```
s1 == s2; // FALSE! (as in first test)
s1 == s1; // true   (as in second test)
```

If you wanted to be more "loose" to arguments, you'd have to write custom argument matchers; Mockito can also do that (with the help of its hamcrest dependency).

All this banter to say that you should solve your problem by making your `Student` class implement `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`.

Comment: You were right about it. Needed equals() and hashCode(). Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help, and sorry for an explanation which could have been simpler!